# Ссылка на массив как возвращаемый тип метода

Tags: php

У меня есть некий метод, который формирует в себе большой массив (примерно 160 МБ).
Необходимо, чтобы метод вернул этот массив.

Вопросы,

1. Стоит ли возвращать ссылку на этот массив, для оптимизации ? (чтобы php не копировал массив, или он сами оптимизирует ?)
2. При возвращении ссылок на переменные из метода, они потом будут работать (т.к. метод выполнился, все локальные переменные удаляются  сборщиком, тогда на что будет ссылаться Ссылка) ?

Версия php 7.2

Comment: Ничего не понятно.....

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.return.php

Comment: Если есть возможность, то лучше замените возвращаемое значение на стрим

Comment: Или на генератор.

Comment: @u_mulder а как применить генератор в моем случае? можно пример плз

Comment: Я ничего не знаю про ваш случай.